# Descobrir erro docker-compose

Tags: java, mysql, docker

Eu possuo o seguinte docker-compose:

```
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
     - "3316:3306"
    volumes:
     - ./database/setup:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
     - ./database/data:/var/lib/mysql
     - ~/Desktop/inserts.sql:/inserts.sql
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=otima
     - MYSQL_USER=otima
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=otima
  web:
    image: tomcat:9.0
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
     - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
     - mysql
    restart: always 
    volumes:
     - ./src/main/webapp:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "100k"
    command: catalina.sh jpda run
    environment:
     JPDA_ADDRESS: "*:8000"
     JPDA_TRANSPORT: dt_socket
     JAVA_OPTS: >
       -Ddatabase.config.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql/otima?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
       -Ddatabase.config.user=otima
       -Ddatabase.config.password=otima
       -Dmail.smtp_host=mailcatcher
       -Dmail.smtp_port=1025
       -Dsite.url=http://localhost:8080
       -Dspring.profiles.active=local
       -Dcluster-master=false
    dns:
      - 8.8.8.8
      - 4.4.4.4
  mailserver:
    image: oninteractive/ubuntu-postfix
    ports:
     - "5080:25"
    environment:
     - "maildomain=mail.leve-me.com"
```

Porem toda vez que rodo ele ele me retorna:leve-me-backend_web_1 exited with code 1
Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado, pesquisei e não encontrei nada a respeito. Esse é o primeiro projeto que pego usando docker.

Answer (score 0):

Tente identificar o seu erro executando o comando na pasta que possui o arquivo docker-compose.yml

```
docker-compose logs
```

O problema relatado está parecendo mais um erro da sua aplicação e não do docker em si.